# Can I speed up the AI getting into vehicles

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

When getting into a vehicle the AI take forever to hop in as well.

Is there a way to speed them up getting in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just drive/fly away in the vehicle the AI will magically appear in it too so there is no need to wait for them!

<sup>**Source:** I found this out myself whilst playing.</sup>

Comment: you posted the question and answered it directly. Is it to have the "answer your own question" achievement?

Comment: @V4karian No it is to share information which isn't frowned upon but actually encouraged. Is there a problem with what I have done?

Comment: Not at all. I was only wondering, and I thought it was a nice way to get it :)

Comment: Actually, the AI will start complaining and asking you if it is because of "that one time" that you don't drive them if you do this frequently enought.

Comment: @DrakaSAN I did this from the start and assumed they always said that...